# Overriding Widget-generated CSS

Tags: html, css, object, embed

I've been tasked with installing a third party widget on a webpage.  When I use the code they give me however, it imports its own CSS along with html, head, body tags and I can't seem to override it.  I've even tried !important.  I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something trivial, if anyone would enlighten me it'd be appreciated.

```
<object data=https://thewebsite.com/eresources/embed?    tab=journal&hideletters=true width="600" height="175"></object>
```

There are pages upon pages of CSS code that the widget references but I think the problem lies within this portion

```
body {
direction:ltr;
margin:0;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
min-height:100%;
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,'DejaVu Sans','Liberation Sans',Freesans,sans-    serif,FontAwesome;
font-size:.75em;
color:#2c2d32;
}
#overlay{
visibility:hidden;
position:fixed;
z-index:5000;
top:0;right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:black;
opacity:0;
transition:opacity linear 0.2s, visibility linear 0 0.4s, top linear 0 0.4s
}

#overlay.shown{
opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity = 40);
visibility:visible;
transition:opacity linear 0.2s, visibility linear 0 0s, top linear 0 0s
}
.neutral-color{ 
color:#777
}

.accent-text{
font-style:italic
}

.ellipses{
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow:ellipsis;
text-overflow:ellipsis
}

.modal{
visibility:hidden;
position:fixed;
z-index:5001;
width:700px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-350px;
opacity:0;
top:0;
margin-top:90px;
margin-bottom:90px;
max-height:calc(100% - 60px);
transition:opacity linear 0.2s, visibility linear 0 .3s, top linear 0 3s
}

.modal.large{
width:900px;
margin-left:-450px
}

.modal.shown{
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity = 40);
visibility:visible;
transition:opacity linear 0.2s, visibility linear 0 0s, top linear 0 0s
}

.modal .modal-dialog{
background-clip:
padding-box;
border:1px solid #999;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-radius:3px;
outline:0;
box-shadow:0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background:white
}

.modal .modal-content>div{
padding:1em
}

.modal .modal-header{
height:46px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc
}

.modal .modal-header h4{
line-height:1.2em;
font-size:1.2em;
margin:0
}

.modal .modal-header button.close{
-webkit-appearance:none;
padding:0;
cursor:pointer;
background:0 0;
border:0
}

.modal .modal-header .close{
cursor:pointer;
float:right;
font-size:21px;
font-weight:700;
line-height:1;
color:#000;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
filter:alpha(opacity=20);
opacity:.2
}

.modal .modal-header .close:hover{
text-decoration:none;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
opacity:.5
}

.modal .modal-footer{
height:46px;
text-align:right;
border-top:1px solid #ccc
}

.modal .modal-body{
overflow:auto
}
```

All of this is wrapped in a second set of , , and  tags.

So far if I use my browser's developer tools to edit the css applied to the widget's body tag (), or the widget's html tag ( ) the changes I need take place however when I go into the actual code and make the changes, they don't stick.

I've tried:
    body.ejm.non-auth {
    background:#EDEEEF;
    }

and  also seem to encompass the same area I'd like to change so for both of those, I tried to make the same change as above but to no avail.

Comment: Try to override by using the widget main div ex. `.main-div .div-you-want-to-style{...}`

Comment: More information is needed to answer the question.  Could you include the style information of the widget in your post, along with the css you've tried?